# VBA three Way IF

Tags: vba

I have three cells that might or might not have data.
If they have data I need to make list out of them

```
If .Cells(16, 5).Text <> "" Then strComment = "- " & .Cells(16, 5).Text & vbCr
If .Cells(17, 5).Text <> "" Then strComment = strComment & "- " & .Cells(17, 5).Text & vbCr
If .Cells(18, 5).Text <> "" Then strComment = strComment & "- " & .Cells(18, 5).Text & vbCr
```

This works but dosen't look nice. There must not be a vbcr at the end.
for two cells I have a solution which eleminats the missing data:

```
         If wksSource.Cells(40, 5).Text <> "" Then strComment = "- " & wksSource.Cells(40, 5).Text
         If wksSource.Cells(41, 5).Text <> "" Then
            If strComment = "" Then
                    strComment = "- " & wksSource.Cells(41, 5).Text
                 Else
                    strComment = strComment & vbCr & "- " & wksSource.Cells(41, 5).Text
                End If
          End If
```

Is there a smarter Solution out there than checking all eight branches with ifs? It could be 0,1,2 or three entries.
Thank you for reading

Comment: Your first code example can be improved by using a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would approach the problem:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Test()
   Dim i As Integer
   Dim strComment As String
   
   For i = 16 To 18
      If Cells(i, 5).Text <> "" Then strComment = strComment & "- " & Cells(i, 5).Text & vbCr
   Next
   
   If Len(strComment) > 0 Then strComment = Left(strComment, Len(strComment) - 1)
   
   MsgBox strComment
End Sub
```

As mentioned in the comments, a loop simplifies the code.  Also, don't worry about the trailing carriage return.  Rather, take care of it outside the loop.

Comment: thx. 
Cutting of the trailing CR is the smart solution I was looking for

Answer (score 1):

I like to use a small utility sub to do this type of thing:

```vb
Sub tester()
    Dim msg As String, c As Range
    msg = ""
    For Each c In ActiveSheet.Cells(16, 5).Resize(3, 1).Cells
        BuildString msg, c.Text
    Next c
    Debug.Print msg
End Sub

Sub BuildString(ByRef msg As String, addText As String)
    If Len(addText) > 0 Then
        If Len(msg) > 0 Then msg = msg & vbCr
        msg = msg & "-" & addText
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: BuildString: Why  byref and not as a function?